# Understanding LWC without APEX?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-recordeditform, attribute, getter

I made a post under the title a few days ago called "Conditional Rendering of a Form Based on Case Status LWC (if:true)"

In that post I talk about how I am trying to set an attribute to the value of an object field that is entered on a form or can be edited. I am a bit lost when it comes to how I can do this and I am mixed up by getters, getFields, getRecords, and connectedCallback. My assumption came to needing to use a connectedCallback as a onInit or when the component loads to set some logic based on the value of the field. What I am not understanding is how to use get, getRecord, or getField properly to retrieve that data (after being updated on the form or not) so I can set the value of the attribute. In Aura components I feel like you would just have a method that is a query. I know this is fundamental but I cannot find or interpret the documentation properly to get what I need. Currently this is my code:

```
    import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Status';
import REASON_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Reason';
import COMMENTS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Comments';

import { getFieldValue, getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


export default class CloseCase extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track thestatus


    thefields = [STATUS_FIELD, REASON_FIELD, COMMENTS_FIELD];

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: thefields})
    case;

      
    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const casefields = event.detail.thefields;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-form').submit(casefields);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        if (this.case.fields.status.value === 'Closed') {
            thestatus = false
        } else {
            thestatus = true
        }  

    }
```

HTML

```
 <template>
    <template if:true={thestatus}>
    <div>
       <lightning-record-form
        record-id={recordId}
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        fields={fields}
        columns="2"
        mode="edit"
        onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
        </lightning-record-form>
    </div>
    </template>

    <template if:false={thestatus}>
        <div>CASE IS CLOSED</div>
    </template>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I explain in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/303462/2984), which is for Aura (but the similar *concepts* are same in LWC), you can't any access any record data in `connetedCallback`, which is approximately the same as `aura:valueInit` in Aura Components. The record has not yet had a chance to load. If you want to set data in your component based on record data, you have to wait for the record to load. In LWC, this is accomplished by using a wire handler:

```
case;
@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: thefields})
  caseWireHandler(result) {
    let { data, error } = result;
    if(data) {
      this.case = result;
      this.thestatus = getFieldValue(data, STATUS_FIELD) === 'Closed'
    }
    if(error) {
      // handle error here
    }
  }
```

Note that track is no longer necessary on primitives in LWC (e.g. you can just write `thestatus` instead of `@track thestatus`), and don't forget to use `this.` to access class properties.

Comment: Ok that is helpful thank you. But if I am trying to set thestatus to a boolean value based on the value of the status field (i.e. if it is 'Closed' it is false else true) would I need to create another variable to set the getfieldvalue() to?

Comment: @TimGeorge The code in this answer does just that. It's just a matter of waiting for the data to load.

Comment: So In this solution how is this.thestatus getting set to true or false. Currently the solution here isn't working. It is rendering the if:false block of HTML and is not changing when I change the status.

Comment: @TimGeorge It should be set after the record is loaded. The if:false will initially be shown until the data is loaded.

Comment: Doesn't the record load with the getRecord method? @sfdcfox

Comment: @akaiprofessional Yes, the getRecord method will get the record and load it. However, this happens after connectedCallback()

Comment: So the connected callback runs before the record is received. In that case shouldn't the "thestatus" attribute have a value of true? I the thestatus is a boolean which you mentioned it is set in the wireHandler. Is the wireHandler the connectedCallback or do I need both.

Comment: thestatus isn't passing data into the field values its value just decides which code block renders

Comment: @akaiprofessional thestatus will be set by the wire handler (in my example), which will be after connectedCallback finishes executing. If you don't set a default value, if:false will trigger on the value.